# This code is running fine but runtime is more. How to execute in less time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Given an array of distinct integers `arr`, find all pairs of elements with the minimum absolute difference of any two elements.

Return a list of pairs in ascending order (with respect to pairs), each pair `[a, b]` follows

- `a, b` are from `arr`
- `a < b`
- `b - a` equals to the minimum absolute difference of any two elements in `arr`.

Example 1:

Input: `arr = [4, 2, 1, 3]`
Output: `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]`
Explanation: The minimum absolute difference is 1. List all pairs with difference equal to 1 in ascending order.

Solution (with less efficiency)

```
class Solution:
    def minimumAbsDifference(self, arr: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        minimum = abs(max(arr)) - (min(arr))
        u = minimum
        for r in arr:
            for t in arr:
                if r - t != 0:
                    minimum = abs(r - t)
                    if minimum < u:
                        u = minimum
                    else:
                        minimum = minimum
        result = []
        for i in arr:
            for x in arr:
                if x != i and abs(i - x) == u and [x, i] not in result and [i, x] not in result:
                    h = [i, x]
                    h.sort()
                    result.append(h)
                    result.sort()
        return result
```

Comment: You could sort the array in the beginning, then iterate it once to find the minimum difference between two neighbours and while iterating remember all the neighbours with the current minimum difference. As soon as you find a lower difference discard the currently remembered neighbours.

Comment: @luk2302. Nice. Eliminate the second pass

Comment: Thank you,

I tried that. it's an improvement on time but I need an even more efficient solution.
let me know if you can think of anything more.

Comment: If you have `minimum = minimum` as your `else` clause, get rid of the `else` or put `pass`

Comment: @luk2302

Dude, I used the same logic in the other loop as well, It worked.
Got it under the time limit.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be obvious that sorting the list will place the elements that are closest together next to eachother. Sorting is generally a O(n log n) operation.

```
arr.sort()
```

Finding the minimum requires a single pass to compare neighboring elements. Pretty much any way you do it will be O(n). A very simple implementation would be

```
x = iter(arr)
next(x)
min_dist = min(b - a for a, b in zip(arr, x))
```

An even simpler one:

```
min_dist = min(arr[i + 1] - arr[i] for i in range(len(arr) - 1))
```

Getting the pairs is now a matter of checking whether any of the differences in any of the generators used to compute `min_diff` are equal to `min_diff`. This is clearly also a O(n) operation.

```
pairs = [arr[i:i + 2] for i in range(len(arr) - 1) if arr[i + 1] - arr[i] == min_diff]
```

Since the complexity of the sort dominates, the overall algorithm is O(n log n), which is likely optimal, and certainly better than the existing O(n^2) implementation.

As [@luk2302 suggests in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70419679/this-code-is-running-fine-but-runtime-is-more-how-to-execute-in-less-time/70419815#comment124480414_70419679), you can avoid the second pass by accumulating pairs with the current minimum value as you go:

```
arr.sort()
if len(arr) < 2: return []
pairs = [arr[:2]]
current_minimum = arr[1] - arr[0]
for i in range(2, len(arr)):
    z = arr[i - 1:i + 1]
    if (n := z[1] - z[0]) < current_minimum:
        pairs = [z]
        current_minimum = n
    elif n == current_minimum:
        pairs.append(z)
```

Comment: Accumulating pairs with the current minimum value is arguably worse than doing a second pass! Especially if the array is `list(range(0,10000,2)) + [10001, 10002]`

Comment: @Stef. Agreed, though list appends are amortized in such a way that the asymptotic complexity won't change

Comment: The space complexity can change, especially for examples where you'd be accumulating a large list but the true result is actually small.

Comment: @Stef. The space complexity will also be O(n) worst case

Comment: Yes, worst-case. In the worst-case, the bad algorithm has the same space complexity as the good algorithm. Just like in the worst-case, bubble sort has the same time complexity as quicksort. There are cases, like the example `list(range(0,2*N,2)) + [2*N+1, 2*N+2]`, where the actual space required is very small (here O(1)), but accumulating pairs with the current minimum value uses space proportional to N.